# ReferenceError: bookshelf is not defined

Tags: javascript, mysql, webpack, karma-jasmine, bookshelf.js

I am running unit tests  using karma-jasmine, webpact.
I tried to insert a record inside a mysql database using bookshelf.
I received the following error message :

**ReferenceError: bookshelf is not defined**
        at module.exports.addCategoryWithProducts (app_serv/order/test/order.util.spec.js:94215:2)
        at Object. (app_serv/order/test/order.util.spec.js:94059:3)
        at ContextKarma.loaded (http://localhost:9876/context.js:151:12)
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
        at Object. (app_serv/order/test/order.util.spec.js:94074:4)

**TypeError: _this.driver.createConnection is not a function**

My code :

```
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'user1',
    password : 'toto',
    database : 'totoDb',
    charset  : 'utf8'
  }
});

module.exports = require('bookshelf')(knex);

module.exports.addCategoryWithProducts = function(categoryToAdd) {

  bookshelf.transaction(function(t) {
    var products = categoryToAdd.products;
    var tableProd = [];

    //if (!req.params.idCategory || req.params.idCategory ==0) {
    Category.forge({
      name: categoryToAdd.name,
      code: categoryToAdd.code,
      tax_percentage: categoryToAdd.tax_percentage,
      description: categoryToAdd.description
    })
      .save(null, { transacting: t })
      .then(function(category) {
        for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
          tableProd.push({
            barcode: products[ i ].barcode,
            cip_13: products[ i ].cip_13,
            category_id: category.id,
            quantity: products[ i ].quantity,
            retail_price: products[ i ].retail_price,
            description: products[ i ].description,
            name: products[ i ].name,
            inn: products[ i ].inn,
            kind: products[ i ].kind,
            comment: products[ i ].comment,
            status: products[ i ].status,
            critical_threshold: products[ i ].critical_threshold,
            max_threshold: products[ i ].max_threshold,
            date_end: products[ i ].date_end
          });
        }

        Products.forge(tableProd)
          .invokeThen('save', null, { transacting: t })
          .then(function(products) {


            //console.log('inside insert of collection '+ JSON.stringify({category : category.toJSON(), produits: products}))
            //res.json({error : false, data: {category : category.toJSON(), products: products}});

            t.commit();

            return Promise.resolve(category.related('products'));
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
            return Promise.reject(err.message);
            //console.log('Erreur dans  Products.forge: ' + err.message);
            res.status(500)
              .json({ error: true, code: err.code, message: err.message });
          })

      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        return Promise.reject(err.message)
        //console.log('Erreur dans  Products.forge: ' + err.message);
        //res.status(500).json({error: true, code : err.code, message: err.message});
      })
  });
}
```

**UNIT TEST CODE:**

```
it("addCategoryWithProducts", function(done){
    addCategoryWithProducts(categoryMock)
        .then(function(catWithPrds){
             expect(catWithPrds).toBeDefined();
             expect(catWithPrds.products).toBeDefined();
             expect(catWithPrds.products.length).toBe(3);
        })

);
```

After trying unsuccessfully many solutions, I decided to ask for your help.

Comment: Your code looks incomplete. Where and how is `bookshelf` defined? And it looks like the code up to `require('bookshelf')(knex);` belongs to another source file.

Comment: Yes, it is in another file. 
I don't think that the problem is there.

Comment: Maybe not, but your error explicitly mentions `bookshelf` to be not defined. So the first think anyone would look at is where and how is it defined. It could help if you split correctly the code segments.

Answer (score 0):

It is not totally clear how your code base works but from `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` it seems you are not properly returning a promise to the unit test.

try changing

```
Products.forge(tableProd)
  .invokeThen('save', null, { transacting: t })
  .then(function(products) {
```

to

```
return Products.forge(tableProd)
  .invokeThen('save', null, { transacting: t })
  .then(function(products) {
```

Also you can simplify your promise and transaction handling:

- You do not need to call `t.commit()` explicitly, since it is automatically called by Bookshelf if the promise resolves
- You normally do not need to use Promise within another Promise. So instead of `return Promise.resolve(category.related('products'))` you could just `return category.related('products')` and instead of `return Promise.reject(err.message)` just `return err.message` (but it would be probably better to re-throw)

Comment: I tried changing my code but I still have the same error message. 
I also simplify my code according to your proposals and I would like to thank you for that

Comment: You mean you are still getting the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` error? Because it was the only one I thought I had enough data about. The `ReferenceError: bookshelf is not defined` and `TypeError: _this.driver.createConnection` errors seem related to how are you defining the `bookshelf` reference.